# How can I make applications open with their taskbar shortcut's icon?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

So I've customized my desktop quite a lot and I have gone with a very minimalistic theme, so I made all my taskbar icons simple and all white. [This is my taskbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKpkr.png)

When I open one of these customized shortcuts, it opens the application without the white icon, like this: https://gyazo.com/e8134b94f8873d24cbf1d4d880575c6c

I would like it to open with my new icons, and I'd prefer not to have to change the default icon in the actual program. It is not extremely important, as it is only an aesthetic concern. Thanks in advance!